# Encrypted whole XML file

Tags: c#, xml, encryption

This websie

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms148633(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms148633%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

encrypted XML file using method:

```
public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementToEncrypt, X509Certificate2 Cert)
```

I want encrypted my whole XML file without second parametr, because I don't want check it my xml file.

Can you give me information, how I should change the code?

Comment: FWIW, this code snippet is a mess: wrong naming conventions, obvious bugs, wrong exceptions thrown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .DocumentElement which will give you the root-node of the document.

```
Encrypt(doc, doc.DocumentElement.Name, cert)
```